# How do I change a readonly property using reflection in PHP 8.1?

Tags: php, reflection, php-8, php-8.1

Is there any way, using reflection or otherwise, to change a readonly property that has already been set?

We sometimes do that in tests, and we don't want to avoid using readonly props just for testing purposes.

```php
class Acme {
    public function __construct(
        private readonly int $changeMe,
    ) {}
}

$object= new Acme(1);
$reflectionClass = new ReflectionClass($object);
$reflectionProperty = $reflectionClass->getProperty('changeMe');
$reflectionProperty->setAccessible(true);
$reflectionProperty->setValue($object, 2);
```

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot modify readonly property Acme::$changeMe
```

Comment: At a cursory glance, the RFC proposing the "readonly" keyword just says "you can't do that": https://wiki.php.net/rfc/readonly_properties_v2#reflection Not posting as an answer, because I haven't looked at the final implementation to see if anything was added later.

Answer (score 4):

The only way I can think of to change a `readonly` property is to reflect the object without calling its constructor. However, not sure if it's useful in your particular case

```
class Acme {
    public function __construct(
        public readonly int $changeMe,
    ) {}
}

$object = new Acme(1);
$reflection = new ReflectionClass($object);
$instance = $reflection->newInstanceWithoutConstructor();
$reflectionProperty = $reflection->getProperty('changeMe');
$reflectionProperty->setValue($instance, 33);

var_dump($reflectionProperty->getValue($instance)); // 33
```

https://3v4l.org/mis1l#v8.1.0

**Note:** we are not actually "changing" the property we are just setting it for the first time since no constructor is called.

Comment: Note: `(new ReflectionProperty($a, 'a'))->setValue($a, 20);` doesn't work, it still results in "Cannot modify readonly property"